# How to change hybrid disk to basic disk in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I created a partition E and then deleted the partition. After that I extended my partition C (where OS was installed) to take the space.

My partition C became hybrid drive.

My hp notebook does not have DVD rom and the notebook only came with an recovery image (I also have a paragon  disc image).

My computer has some problems now and I want to recover it by either the factory format or the paragon disc image. However, none of them works.

I know it is because my disc has become hybrid disk. My question is how to fix the dynamic disk problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Buy a usb DVD drive and use HP recovery DVD's to do a factory recovery, back up your data as everything will be wiped on all partitions.
2. Use Software to [change partitions back to basic](http://www.partition-tool.com/resource/convert-dynamic-disk-to-basic.htm). EaseUS Partition Master Home edition is Free and can do this.

[Here is how to properly make](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-Notebook-PC-Questions/How-to-repartition-HDD-of-HP-notebook-with-pre-loaded-Windows-7/m-p/742019) a 5th partition on a HP notebook once you get things sorted out

Comment: Is it possible to take out the hard drive and connect it to another computer as an external hard drive, format the hard drive and put it back ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? define "format"